# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported occurs when try to submit spring security's custom login form

Tags: spring

I am using spring, spring security. My application have custom login page a jsp page where i am trying to post username, password and csrf token, and in backend  i have a controller to capture and authenticate login details. I am using tomcat. I am using spring security for login authentication. Getting the following error when i submitting login form  the file HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported Any ideas?

Login Page:

```
<div id="login-box">

    <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>

    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="error">${error}</div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
        <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
    </c:if>

    <form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/login' />" method='POST'>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />

    </form>
</div>
```

Controller Class:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Custom Login Form");
    model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
    model.setViewName("hello");
    return model;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Custom Login Form");
    model.addObject("message", "This is protected page!");
    model.setViewName("admin");

    return model;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if (error != null) {
        model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }
    model.setViewName("login");

    return model;

}
```

Spring-Security Config:

```
<http auto-config="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <form-login 
    login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
    authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
    username-parameter="username"
    password-parameter="password" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
  <!-- enable csrf protection -->
  <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok the problem I see here is in the jsp form. The form action is not correct, spring security tries to do login processing with some other action by default. i.e. **/j_spring_security_check** and even the field names are not correct in your mail.

```
Username field : j_username
Password field : j_password
```

So you need to do three things to get this working.

1. Rename action in form declaration in jsp to action="
2. Rename username field to j_username
3. Rename password field to j_password

Spring security does provide flexibilities to rename all, but lets get the basic one working first. No other changes are expected

**EDIT:**

I missed reading the username and password customization.

Just do one thing (Have added login-processing-url property):

```
<http auto-config="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <form-login 
     login-page="/login" 
     default-target-url="/welcome" 
     authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
     login-processing-url="/login"
     username-parameter="username"
     password-parameter="password" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
  <!-- enable csrf protection -->
  <csrf/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you redirect to login page with

```
model.setViewName("login");
```

Do you use spring security? If yes, I don't see in your code anything related to the spring security filter.

I suggest you to have a look over there

[mykong example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-custom-login-form-annotation-example/)

or obviously to 
[spring-reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration)

Answer (score -2):

Your controller accept only GET request, your form use POST. First of all I will try to change this configuration.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

You can also avoid to specify the option method, which should mean GET and POST.

Comment: When I avoid to specify the option method, it shows login page.But when I try to submit login form with correct credentials, it shows the login form only. What could be a problem?

Comment: Thanx for your quick response. I followed your suggestions but still not worked.